# Resize each table on a worksheet with a variable number of rows

Tags: vba, excel

I’m new to VBA, I’m struggling with a piece of code, and I’m hoping someone can help. I have a series of 78 tables, each with 1 column, in Sheet 1 of Workbook 1 (ThisWorkbook), named Table A through Table BZ, respectively. Each table is the source for a corresponding named range, “_TableA” through “_TableBZ” that I’m using to drive a series of dependent drop-downs on Sheet 2.

I have figured out the code to copy and paste values from Workbook 2 into each of the 78 tables in Workbook 1, one table at a time, effectively refreshing the available choices in the dependent drop-downs. If the number of values pasted from Workbook 2 is greater than the size of the table in Workbook 1, the table in Workbook 1 is automatically resized to fit the updated dataset. If the number of values pasted from Workbook 2 is less than the size of the table in Workbook 1, the table needs to be resized so that blank values don’t show up in the dependent drop-downs.

I started by trying to include the resize the table within the copy / paste loop but couldn’t seem to get the variables defined properly and struggled with choosing between the Range.Resize and ListObjects.Resize methods. I’ve now tried to create a second loop to go through all the tables and resize one at a time after all the copying / pasting is done. Is there any difference in the two approaches?

I can resize Table A with the following code, but it doesn’t progress to Table B in the next loop (i = 2).

```
Dim CurrentTable As ListObject
i = 1
Do
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set CurrentTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    CurrentTable.Resize Range("N1:N10")
    i = i + 1
Loop Until i = 78
```

I also need to resize each table to an appropriate number of rows, so I tried including another range variable. The following code does not resize Table A and gives me an Application-defined or object-defined error on “CurrentTable.Resize Range(TableRange)”:

```
Dim TableRange As Range
Dim CurrentTable As ListObject
i = 1
Do
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set CurrentTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    Set TableRange = Range(CurrentTable).Resize (CurrentTable.Range.Rows.Count, 1)
    CurrentTable.Resize Range(TableRange)
    i = i + 1
Loop Until i = 78
```

I thought that the Rows.Count in the Resize range might be messing it up, but Resize(CurrentTable.Range.Rows,1) gives me the same error.

So I need some combination that will resize the CurrentTable to the number of rows that contain data and then move to the next table in the series.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more generic version of the previous code

[image]

---

.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub resizeTables()
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each tbl In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
        cleanUpTable tbl
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

.

This Sub removes duplicate values and sorts the items in the first column of the table

```
Private Sub cleanUpTable(ByRef tbl As ListObject) 'fails if tbl is Nothing
    Dim ws As Worksheet, db As Range, ur As Range
    Dim fr As Long, lr As Long, fc As Long, dr As Long

    Set ws = tbl.Parent:    Set ur = ws.UsedRange:  Set db = tbl.DataBodyRange
    fc = db.Column:         fr = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row

    lr = ws.Cells(ur.Row + ur.Rows.Count, fc).End(xlUp).Row

    If lr > db.Row + db.Rows.Count - 1 Then                             'check beyond tbl
        tbl.Resize ws.Range(ws.Cells(fr, fc), ws.Cells(lr, fc))
    End If

    tbl.HeaderRowRange(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes    'get unique values

    Set db = tbl.DataBodyRange
    dr = ws.Cells(db.Row + db.Rows.Count - 1, fc).End(xlUp).Row

    If dr > db.Row Then     'if table has more than 1 row, sort 1st column A-Z
        With tbl.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = True
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortFields.Add Key:=tbl.HeaderRowRange(1), Order:=xlAscending
            .Apply
        End With
    Else
        If dr = 1 Then tbl.Resize ws.Range(ws.Cells(fr, fc), db.Cells(1))
    End If

    lr = ws.Cells(ur.Row, fc).End(xlDown).Row
    tbl.Resize ws.Range(ws.Cells(fr, fc), ws.Cells(lr, fc))
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(lr + 1, fc), ws.Cells(ur.Row + ur.Rows.Count, fc)).Delete xlShiftUp
End Sub
```

---

This is the above Sub but it doesn't sort or remove duplicates:

```
Private Sub cleanUpTable(ByRef tbl As ListObject) 'fails if tbl is Nothing
    Dim ws As Worksheet, db As Range, ur As Range
    Dim fr As Long, lr As Long, fc As Long, dr As Long

    Set ws = tbl.Parent:    Set ur = ws.UsedRange:  Set db = tbl.DataBodyRange
    fc = db.Column:         fr = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row

    lr = ws.Cells(ur.Row + ur.Rows.Count, fc).End(xlUp).Row

    If lr > db.Row + db.Rows.Count - 1 Then                             'check beyond tbl
        tbl.Resize ws.Range(ws.Cells(fr, fc), ws.Cells(lr, fc))
    End If

    lr = ws.Cells(ur.Row, fc).End(xlDown).Row
    tbl.Resize ws.Range(ws.Cells(fr, fc), ws.Cells(lr, fc))
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(lr + 1, fc), ws.Cells(ur.Row + ur.Rows.Count, fc)).Delete xlShiftUp
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Paul. The ranges are contiguous - my apologies for not being specific about that. This works beautifully when there is more than 1 row of data in the DataBodyRange. In tables with only 1 row of data in the DataBodyRange, it resizes to include the entire column. In tables that need to be resized down to just 1 row in the DataBodyRange, it doesn't seem to do anything. I tried using ".End(xlUp).Row" but no luck. Thanks again for taking the time!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I made some changes and the edited answer handles empty tables and DataBodyRange with one value only. If this works please mark the answer as accepted as a reference for others

Comment: Fantastic. Works perfectly!